# Use of other protocol method in extend-type

Tags: clojure

I'm building a graph editor with Piccolo2D and want to implement [Loom](https://github.com/aysylu/loom/)'s `Graph` protocol. However I run into problem

```
Unable to resolve symbol: out-edges in this context
```

What really confusing is that I can use `successors` in `has-edge`.

```
(extend-type PCanvas
  Graph
  (nodes [g]
    (->children (->node-layer g)))

  (edges [g]
    (->children (->edge-layer g)))

  (has-node? [g node]
    (some #{node} (nodes g)))

  (has-edge? [g n1 n2]
    (some #{n2} (successors g n1)))

  (successors
    ([g] (partial successors g))
    ([g node]
       (remove (partial = node)
               (distinct (flatten (apply concat 
                                         (map ->nodes (out-edges g node))))))))

  (out-degree [g node]
    (count (out-edges g node)))

  (out-edges [g node]
    (->edges node)))
```

So in what condition protocol methods can call others?

Edit: Full error message: http://pastebin.com/NDWEZZ7y

Comment: Normally (iirc) protocol implementations should be able to call the protocol methods themselves freely. Can you post the full error message?

Comment: Yep, that's what I thought too. I added the full error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such method in the current release, 0.4.2, which is 4 months old, see https://github.com/aysylu/loom/blob/0.4.2/src/loom/graph.clj#L13. You are probably looking at the master branch in GitHub, [changes made 23 days ago](https://github.com/aysylu/loom/commit/9b0ab2c771b3b901571fa94901ea1e5ca0ef5439#diff-a31e44159577e8a63db02a5319c54c4a), not yet in a release.

Answer (score 2):

I released Loom version 0.5.0 which includes the multigraph support.